# How to remove public from url in sub folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I want to host my laravel website in subfolder like below:-

```
public_html/ecommerce/
```

Actually i have one more laravel website in public_html for that i have removed the public from url frorm below htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

But if add same htaccess in public_html/ecommerce its not working at all beacause its may be due to sub folder

I have searched on google some one told below points:-

```
1) Rename server.php to index.php 
2) copy .htacces from public to root
 This is working but my all assets path like css jss are not fetching for that i need to add public in each asset link.
```

Can anybody help me how can i do in htccess level only. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using vps or cpanel ?

Comment: hello i am using cpanel

Comment: i have tried for subdomain also for some reasons i can't use subomain

Answer (score 0):

your directory structure must be,

public_html

- laravel_app1
- laravel_app2
- laravel_app3

in each laravel application root directory create .htaccess that is, laravel_app1/.htaccess, laravel_app2/.htaccess and so on. In each .htaccess add rules sth like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

finally you can access website as, yourdomain.com/laravel_app1 yourdomain.com/laravel_app2 and so on

Comment: <IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
whats this?

Comment: AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
how to use this?

Comment: this module provides   for determining the types of files from the filename.

Comment: i have copy and paste you code in htaccess but its not working

Comment: correct location of .htaccess file is, your_app/.htaccess not in public directory

Comment: yes i have added in public_html/ecommerce/.htaccess

Comment: its showing  "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: in cpanel there should be ERRORS package, go there and read error logs, if possible send me

Comment: [Thu Jun 13 04:46:21.267564 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 415057:tid 140364878436096] [client 110.225.211.0:0] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/sbl1972/public_html/ecommerce/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: which version of php are you using

Comment: its php 7.2 i am using

Comment: change it to 7.1

Comment: i have changed to 7.1 but same issue coming

Comment: its not working  with www.example.com/ecommerce.................................
but its work with its not working www.example.com/ecommerce/public

Comment: have you removed or change .htaccess inside public folder, leave as it is

Comment: why are you trying to access /public that is www.example.com/ecommerce/public

Comment: i have not tocuhed htaccess file in public directory as i am doing modifications in ecommerce/.htaccess file

Comment: www.example.com/ecommerce/    it must work with this url

Comment: have you found any solution?